# Как в QLabel выводить текст с задержкой, чтобы была плавность

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qtimer

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QLabel, QInputDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.text = f'После того, как запустите этот код, обратите внимание на то,\nчто ярлык возникает некорректно, так как\
 размер — меньше,\nчем размер шрифта, который мы используем. Так что нам\nнужно установить размер ярлыка.'
        self.lbl4 = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl4.setGeometry(20, 290, 460, 90)
        self.resize(400, 500)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Квест')

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.print_text)

    def print_text(self):
        new = []

        for letter in [i for i in self.text]:
            new.append(letter)
            self.lbl4.setText(''.join(new))
            self.lbl4.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
            self.timer.start(30)
            self.update()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QLabel, QInputDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.text = f'После того, как запустите этот код, обратите внимание на то,\nчто ярлык возникает некорректно, так как\
 размер — меньше,\nчем размер шрифта, который мы используем. Так что нам\nнужно установить размер ярлыка.'
        self.lbl4 = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl4.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.lbl4.setGeometry(20, 290, 460, 90)
        self.resize(400, 500)
#?        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Квест')

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.print_text)
        self.timer.start(50)

        self.new = [i for i in self.text] # []
        self.len_new = len(self.new)
        self.num = 0

    def print_text(self):
        self.lbl4.setText(self.lbl4.text() + self.new[self.num])
        self.num += 1
        if self.num == self.len_new: self.timer.stop()
#        new = []
#        for letter in [i for i in self.text]:
#            new.append(letter)
#            self.lbl4.setText(''.join(new))
#            self.lbl4.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
#            self.timer.start(30)
#            self.update()
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @kostya_09   я ответил на ваш вопрос ?